# Swift view method call on app exit

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently working on an iOS app with Swift and I've run into a bit of a problem with regards to the view appearing and disappearing handling.

I'm aware that by overriding `viewWillDisappear` you can handle when within the app the view is being exited out of.
I'm also aware that in the `AppDelegate` you can implement code in `applicationWillTerminate` to do certain things when the user exits out of / closes the app.

My question is the following: is there a way for me to know that the application will terminate from my view controller code?

Comment: The application will terminate method and notification may not be executed/posted in the case where the user terminate the app from the app switcher

Answer (score 1):

You can have your controller register for a UIApplicationWillTerminate notification, which is delivered under the same conditions as applicationWillTerminate.

See the UIApplicationDelegate docs for more details about the timing of state transitions.

Comment: I've been looking through the documentation but I can't seem to find any useful information as to how I am to register for those notifications. Would you have to know where I could find a quick example?